# Rounded corners on jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider, rounded-corners

Site: http://aquajardin.petersenuploads.co.uk

I'm using http://slidesjs.com/ and while I've set my inner containers with background images and rounded corners, I still see the square corner poking out when the slide transitions. Any ideas how I can fix this?

I've now added a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jeepstone/VgK7d/1/

For some reason JSFiddle wont show my images, but the code is correct.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you include minimal code and a screenshot of the rendering in the question instead of the link? Otherwise when you fix the issue the question loses a lot of its value.

Comment: Sorry, good point. I'll put a jsfiddle together.

Comment: Now done at http://jsfiddle.net/jeepstone/VgK7d/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `#slides`

Comment: Sorry alpaca, doesn't fix it.

Comment: Tried this with Chrome just now.  Didn't help.